# Databricks Spark CSV header delimiter

Tags: apache-spark, spark-csv

Our csv file has the format of ^A as being our column delimiter and ^B as being our line delimter/record delimiter.
So I am using the databricks spark csv library to create a dataframe the following way:

```
val dataFrame = cassSqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
      .option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true")
      .option("delimiter", "\u0001").load(file)
```

Looking at the documentation for spark csv, regarding the headers option, it says this:
 when set to true the first **line** of files will be used to name columns and will not be included in data. All types will be assumed string. Default value is false.

However we are not using \n, rather we are using ^B. So is there a way to tell the spark csv library that our headers has a delimiter as well rather than the default \n

Comment: I'm afraid there is no way to modify the record delimiter when parsing CSV with Spark. On a side node csv parsing is now part of spark (starting from 2.0 if I recall correctly). You can do `spark.read.csv("/tmp/my.csv")`

Comment: Yea but currently we are using spark 1.6 but I figured out a solution

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get the above code working by adding this following line for my sparkContext:

sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter", "\u0002")